# My Minecraft folder got wiped clean in Mac, and Minecraft is messed up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

And no, I did not move, delete, or even touch the Minecraft folder manually recently. I am able to play Minecraft literally 10 minutes ago, and then I closed Minecraft, and when I open Minecraft again, I realised that all my worlds, resource packs, server saves, etc. are wiped clean. I can't even see Minecraft app. The Minecraft folder is totally messed up. I did not see my files inside Trash.

What happened? Why did this happen, and how can I recover my files?

[EDIT] Minecraft.app is not there. Why did this happen?

Comment: I had to totally reinstall Minecraft. And all my worlds are gone. *poof*

Comment: could be your antivirus, were you running any mods?

Comment: I don't have antivirus, and I am running Minecraft 1.8.3 before The Wipe.

Comment: were you running any mods?

Comment: No I am not running any mods. Clean vanilla 1.8.3.

Comment: try this http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Recover_corrupted_saved_world_data#For_Mac_OS_X

Comment: What do you mean by the Minecraft folder is totally messed up? Is it missing?

Answer (score -1):

Use this guide to find the minecraft data folder: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/finding-minecraft-data-folder/

In this folder verify that /saves is present and contains your worlds. If it doesn't, then your worlds are gone unless you have a backup.